# How to extract facial features using dlib

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I need to extract feature points and convert them to a YAML file. Uptil now the code I have is:

```
#pragma once
#include "facial_feature_points.h"


using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

const string model_path = "../src/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat";

int facial_feature_detector (const string& img_path) {

    try {

        frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector ();
        shape_predictor s_predict;
        deserialize (model_path) >> s_predict;

        image_window win_a, win_b;

        array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
        load_image (img, img_path);
        pyramid_up (img);

        std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector (img);
        cout << "Number of faces detected: " << dets.size () << endl;
        std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;

        std::vector <double> landmarks;

        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < dets.size (); ++j) {
            full_object_detection shape = s_predict (img, dets[j]);
            cout << "number of parts: "<< shape.num_parts () << endl;
            cout << "pixel position of first part:  " << shape.part (0) << endl;
            cout << "pixel position of second part: " << shape.part (1) << endl;
            shapes.push_back(shape);
            double 
        }


        win_a.clear_overlay ();
        win_a.set_image (img);
        win_a.add_overlay (render_face_detections (shapes));

        dlib::array <array2d <rgb_pixel> > face_chips;
        extract_image_chips (img, get_face_chip_details(shapes), face_chips);
        win_b.set_image (tile_images (face_chips));



        // disp_landmarks (img_path, dets, shapes);



    } catch (exception& e) {
        cout << "\n[!] Exception thrown:  " << e.what () << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int shape_to_np (const full_object_detection& shape) {

    for (int i=0; i<68; ++i )

    return 0;
}


// TODO: resolve the problem in compilation
/*
void disp_landmarks (const string& img, const std::vector <rectangle> dets, const std::vector <full_object_detection> shapes) {
    image_window win;
    win.clear_overlay ();
    win.set_image (img);

    for (int i=0; i<shapes.size(); ++i)
        win.add_overlay (shapes[i]);

    win.add_overlay (dets);
    // hit_enter_to_continue ();
    win.wait_until_closed ();
}
*/
```

I need to convert the landmarks into separate 68 points. I have found this python code for the conversion:

```
def _shape_to_np(shape):
    xy = []
    for i in range(68):
        xy.append((shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y,))
    xy = np.asarray(xy, dtype='float32')
    return xy
```

But I dont know how to recreate it in c++. Please help . It would also work if you could just explain what this python code is doing. I am not fluent at python and the code is a bit weird for me to understand.

Comment: Its good to see dlib's samples code here. But where is your code for opening yaml file for writing ... ?

Comment: The Python code does nothing interesting. It converts the data from a structured type to a flat array of [float,float].

Comment: @RadLexus Thanks a lot. I am just not used to python's syntax so skipped this simple code

Comment: (An unrelated but quick tip: take a look at Python! If you have any experience with other programming languages, you'll soon pick it up.)

Comment: @JohnDoe you should see for writing on a YAML file.